# Error when using function preg_replace() in php of wampserver

Tags: php

I have a function:

```
function filter($str) { 
            $str = preg_replace("/(à|á|ạ|ả|ã|â|ầ|ấ|ậ|ẩ|ẫ|ă|ằ|ắ|ặ|ẳ|ẵ)/", 'a', $str); 
            $str = preg_replace("/(è|é|ẹ|ẻ|ẽ|ê|ề|ế|ệ|ể|ễ)/", 'e', $str); 
            $str = preg_replace("/(ì|í|ị|ỉ|ĩ)/", 'i', $str); 
            $str = preg_replace("/(ò|ó|ọ|ỏ|õ|ô|ồ|ố|ộ|ổ|ỗ|ơ|ờ|ớ|ợ|ở|ỡ)/", 'o', $str); 
            $str = preg_replace("/(ù|ú|ụ|ủ|ũ|ư|ừ|ứ|ự|ử|ữ)/", 'u', $str); 
            $str = preg_replace("/(ỳ|ý|ỵ|ỷ|ỹ)/", 'y', $str); 
            $str = preg_replace("/(đ)/", 'd', $str); 
            $str = preg_replace("/(À|Á|Ạ|Ả|Ã|Â|Ầ|Ấ|Ậ|Ẩ|Ẫ|Ă|Ằ|Ắ|Ặ|Ẳ|Ẵ)/", 'A', $str); 
            $str = preg_replace("/(È|É|Ẹ|Ẻ|Ẽ|Ê|Ề|Ế|Ệ|Ể|Ễ)/", 'E', $str); 
            $str = preg_replace("/(Ì|Í|Ị|Ỉ|Ĩ)/", 'I', $str); 
            $str = preg_replace("/(Ò|Ó|Ọ|Ỏ|Õ|Ô|Ồ|Ố|Ộ|Ổ|Ỗ|Ơ|Ờ|Ớ|Ợ|Ở|Ỡ)/", 'O', $str); 
            $str = preg_replace("/(Ù|Ú|Ụ|Ủ|Ũ|Ư|Ừ|Ứ|Ự|Ử|Ữ)/", 'U', $str); 
            $str = preg_replace("/(Ỳ|Ý|Ỵ|Ỷ|Ỹ)/", 'Y', $str); 
            $str = preg_replace("/(Đ)/", 'D', $str); 
            $str = preg_replace("/(–)/", ' ', $str); 
            $str = str_replace(" ", "-", str_replace("&*#39;","",$str)); 
            return $str; 
        }
$test = "Chào thế giới";
echo filter($test);
```

I using wampserver, when run code is error:

```
Warning: preg_replace() [function.preg-replace]: Compilation failed: nothing to repeat at offset 5 in C:\wamp\www\xxx.php on line xx
```

How to config this error, if result exactly `is chao-the-gioi`

Comment: line xx? Which line no does it states?

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to use str_replace for this? It has the array mode just for this use case, y'know: http://php.net/str_replace Even better, why not use `iconv` to ASCII to get rid of diacritics? (you're skipping most of `ěščřž` with your whitelist; and I've only been mashing the keyboard for a second)

Comment: Definitely the probl here is of regex pattern used

Answer (score 0):

PHP does not treat `ù` as a single character unless you specify the `u` modifier.  Etc.  It treats is as a multi-byte string in the default character set -- hence preg_replace gets "confused".

Comment: The `u` flag stands for `UTF-8` so you need it if your files are actually using UTF-8. (Of course, you can store accented characters in many other encodings.)

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario, +1 but the example is UTF-8 -- that's my point.  I don't know of any single-byte encoding which offers this character range.  The OPs editor will "see"  UTF-8 but by default PHP will use the server's default character set.  In this case `"/(Đ)/u" is what is needed, etc.